# Converting slow functions to promise for async in Pinia

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pinia

I have some Pinia actions that take a little time to run, and would like to convert them to promises, to help me better understand promises.

I have two actions that take some time to run in this format.

```
longFunction1(inDat){
// Manipulate inDat and eventually:
return outArray
}

longFunction2(inDat){
// Manipulate inDat and eventually:
return outArray
}

fetchData(){
const dat1 = this.longFunction1(this.array);
const dat2 = this.longFunction2(dat1);

this.fetchedData = dat2;
}
```

Do I change `longFunction1()` and `longFunction2()` to return a promise and chain `.then()` and set `fecthedData` as the resolved data of the other two functions?

Comment: Converting slow blocking code to a promise still leaves it as slow blocking code. It doesn't make it run in a parallel thread or anything. Converting to use promises will not help much.

Comment: I'm not too worried about speeding it up, it will just make the loading spinners easier to manage and have the data load in properly.

Comment: It probably won't do any of that as synchronous code that works on the main UI thread will block the showing/operation of spinners *as well as  any UI updates*.